# Does the adaptive cruise control system involves very complex calculus for a high school student?

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, derivatives, complex-numbers, physics

I am a high school student and I have a math essay due in 3 days. I am interested in cars, so I decided to talk about calculus and integration(even though I have never studied in my whole life) in cars and it was about the adaptive cruise control system, but then I realized that it was very complex after understanding the basic introduction in calculus. In conclusion, do you think I can manage to explore how adaptive cruise control works or is it too complex, if not please help me with a topic of cars maybe involving complex numbers because I think cars use complex numbers in their system and I am a higher level student so complex numbers would be good in my level?
I appreciate your valuable help!!!

Comment: I used to enjoy mathematics at school for the simple reason that we didn't have to write essays. And then to make the students not only write essays, but also to dream up the subject they want to write the essays on? Appalling.

Comment: oh yes, then this for sure looks hard!!!

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for something involving cars (what I wrote in the question)??